# Variable listener in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, variables, listener, status, didset

I am trying to make an independent class/library that runs on its own and handles errors internally, but also gives feedback (status) to the frontend for possible user interaction. In Android I'd solve this with a Listener:

```
    class Status(errCode:Int=0, msg:String=""){
    var errCode:Int=0
    var text:String=""
    private var listener: ChangeListener? = null

    init {
        this.errCode=errCode
        this.text=msg
    }

    fun set(errCode:Int, msg:String) {
        this.errCode=errCode
        this.text=msg
        if (listener != null) listener!!.onChange()
    }

    fun getListener(): ChangeListener? {
        return listener
    }

    fun setListener(listener: ChangeListener?) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    interface ChangeListener {
        fun onChange()
    }
}
```

Whenever I want to update it, e.g. on Exception, I call:

```
catch (e: IOException) {
            this.status.set(109,"someException: $e")
        }
```

And in the MainActivity I just have to handle these changes:

```
myObj.status.setListener(object : Status.ChangeListener {
            override fun onChange() {
                when(myObj!!.status.errCode) {
                    //errors
                    109 -> log(myObj!!.status.text) //some Exception
                    111 -> myObj!!.restart() //another exc
                    112 -> myObj!!.checkAll() //some other error
...
```

In Swift I found didSet that seems similar. I read you can attach it to a struct so whenever something in the struct changes, it is called. So I added my "struct Status" to my "struct myObj" like this:

```
struct myObj {
var status:Status=Status(errCode: 0, msg: "Init")

struct Status {
    var errCode:Int
    var msg:String
    
    mutating func set(err:Int, txt:String){
        errCode=err
        msg=txt
    }
}
```

and in my code I initialize a new instance of myObj

```
var mObj:myObj=myObj.init() {
        didSet{
            switch myObj.status.errCode{
            case 1:
                promptOkay()
            case 113:
                obj.errorHandling()
            default:
                log(txt: mObj.status.msg)
            }
        }
    }
```

However, it never trigger didSet, even though internal functions should change the Status. I read that didSet is not triggered on init, but I do not run anything right now after initializing the class object that should run quite independently. I want to verify that the approach is okay before I go further and have to unravel everything again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didSet` must be declared on the property, not during initialization:

```swift
class MyObj {
    var status: Status = Status(errCode: 0, msg: "Init") {
        didSet {
            // status did change
            print("new error code: \(status.errCode)")
        }
    }
    
    struct Status {
        var errCode:Int
        var msg:String
        
        mutating func set(err:Int, txt:String){
            errCode = err
            msg = txt
        }
    }
}

let obj = MyObj()
obj.status.set(err: 10, txt: "error 10") // prints "new error code: 10"
```

At this point you can react to every changes made to `obj.status` in the `didSetClosure`.

**Edit — React to didSet from outside the class**

If you want to respond to changes from outside the `MyObj`, I would recommend using a closure:

```swift
class MyObj {
    var status: Status = Status(errCode: 0, msg: "Init") {
        didSet {
            statusDidChange?(status)
        }
    }
    
    // closure to call when status changed
    var statusDidChange: ((Status) -> Void)? = nil
    
    struct Status {
        var errCode:Int
        var msg:String
        
        mutating func set(err:Int, txt:String){
            errCode = err
            msg = txt
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can assign a closure from outside to perform custom actions:

```swift
let obj = MyObj()
obj.statusDidChange = { status in
    // status did change
    print("new error code: \(status.errCode)")
}

obj.status.set(err: 10, txt: "error 10") // prints "new error code: 10"
```

**Edit 2 — Call didSet closure directly from initialization**

You also can manually call the `statusDidChange` closure during the init.

```swift
class MyObj {
    var status: Status = Status(errCode: 0, msg: "Init") {
        didSet {
            statusDidChange(status)
        }
    }
    
    // closure to call when status changed
    var statusDidChange: (Status) -> Void
    
    init(status: Status, statusDidChange: @escaping (Status) -> Void) {
        self.status = status
        self.statusDidChange = statusDidChange
        self.statusDidChange(status)
    }
}

let obj = MyObj(status: MyObj.Status(errCode: 9, msg: "error 09")) { status in
    // status did change
    print("new error code: \(status.errCode)")
}

obj.status.set(err: 10, txt: "error 10")
```

This will print

```
new error code: 9
new error code: 10
```

Comment: I tried this actually, and it triggers a change, but my goal was to get the change from outside the MyObj struct/class, so a frontend developer can use it for actions/prompts. didSet has to be called on an initialization btw, that is exactly what you did, just you called it on the Status init. But I am just thinking I can make status a standalone struct that MyObj can refer to, i.e. I declare it in the main code "var status= Status(...){didSet...}" and hand it to MyObj: "var mObj=MyObj(status: status...)"; then I can just call status.set inside the class. I'll try this right now!

Comment: I edited my answer to be able to forward the didSt outside of `MyObj`

Comment: Great! My idea didn't work really, but I tried yours and compared the code, and the main issue seemed that it really doesn't trigger at init(). I need to set the init first, then call a func that triggers a change after (i.e. not from the init()). But your closure makes it also nice, because now only changes in status trigger on frontend, not all changes to the struct! In short: it is important to do "class.init()" that sets the didSet and then call some "class.start()" that triggers changes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can manually call the `statusDidChange` closure during the init if you need to. I edited with this case.